# How to pop up message if the user put other value which is not in combobox list?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 item in my combobox list.

If the user put different value(example.12) which is not among them and press the button then I want to show the message box.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you be allowing them to enter a different value in the first place? If you only want them to select a value from the drop-down list then only let them select a value from the drop-down list, i.e. set the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList` instead of the default `DropDown`. This is a perfect example of why you should ALWAYS read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The first option should be to force the user to select an item from the drop-down list rather than type in freehand. You do that by setting the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList` instead of `DropDown`. In that case, typing character will select the next item that starts with that character if one exists and do nothing otherwise.

If you must allow the user to type into the control freehand then you should use the validation functionality built into the control. That means handling the `Validating` event to validate the control contents and prevent it losing focus if it fails. You can also handle the `Validated` event to do something after the control passes validation. That might look like this:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
    If ComboBox1.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso Not ComboBox1.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) Then
        ComboBox1.SelectAll()

        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item in the drop-down list",
                        "Invalid Item",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        'Don't let the control lose focus.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validated
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindStringExact(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

In that case, the user will not be able to leave the control until they select or enter a valid value, which would include no text at all. Once they do select or enter a valid value and shift focus, the corresponding item in the drop-down list will be selected. If you don't do that, the user could enter a valid value but the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` would still be `Nothing` and -1 respectively.

Comment: I completely agree with what you're saying about the DropDownStyle and validation handling, it's always better to stop garbage in then to mop it up later this doesn't answer the question.  Poster specifically asked to pop up a message on button click

Answer (score 2):

```
If Not ComboBox1.Items.Contains(userInput) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Number not in list")
End If
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private nums() As String = {"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100"}
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(nums)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not nums.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number that appears in the drop down.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Good Number!")
    End If
End Sub
```